# How to make canvas full screen in AR.JS

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I'm tring to match the whole screen in AR.JS, but I'm confused some options in AR.JS, here are my options right now, but these settings cannot make canvas full screen.

```js
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;


let arToolkitSource = new THREEx.ArToolkitSource({
  sourceType: "webcam",
  sourceWidth: width,
  sourceHeight: height,
  displayWidth: width,
  displayHeight: height,
});


let arToolkitContext = new THREEx.ArToolkitContext({
  cameraParametersUrl: "data/data/camera_para.dat",
  detectionMode: "mono",
  canvasWidth: width,
  canvasHeight: height,
  maxDetectionRate: 60,
});
```

Comment: this will stay forever a secret